# Подключение библиотеки, написанной на .NET 6.0 к приложению, написанному на Qt, под Linux

Tags: c#, linux, .net, qt

Имеется библиотека, написанная на **C#** с помощью **.NET 6.0**, для **Linux**. Можно ли подключить данную библиотеку к приложению, написанному на **Qt**? (Если бы это необходимо было сделать под Windows, то можно было бы воспользоваться технологией COM.) А можно ли подключить такую библиотеку к приложению на Qt под **Linux**?

Comment: Первая мысль: создать [оболочку](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1185716/how-to-use-c-objects-returned-in-qt) на C++/CLI, а уже её вызывать в Qt. Но под линуксом это не заведётся... / Я вижу единственный вариант: Преобразовать библиотеку в полноценную программу, которую запускать самостоятельно. Наладить межпроцессное взаимодействие между этой программой и программой на Qt.

Comment: Если переписать библиотеку на .NET 7, то становится доступно Native AOT. Код, скомпилированный AOT использует конвенции C, т. е. его можно вызывать откуда угодно! Правда, далеко не каждую либу удастся так скомпилировать. В частности, не поддерживается динамическая кодогенерация, рефлексия (а следовательно и многие виды сериализации). Но посмотреть в этом направлении определённо стоит.